# Reverse OpenVPN connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, openvpn

I am close to getting this to work but need some assistance.

I have `OpenVPN` Access server running on a `Droplet` in Digital ocean.

I have a `RaspberryPi` with a wireless connection on my network.
**`IP =  192.168.20.205`**

The user the pi connects to the Access server is set to be a VPN gateway with :
Allow Access From: all server-side private subnets
Allow Access From: all other *VPN* clients
**`192.168.20.0/24.`**

I have another user that connects to the Access server without the gateway settings.
When both users connect I can see them both in the web GUI of the access server with an IP assigned. **`172.27.232.XXX`**

Now from the remote user I can ping the Pis **`172.xxx.xxx.xxx`** IP address and even SSH into it using the 172 address.

However, it seems like the Pi isn't bridging / routing correctly or getting stopped by a firewall, as from the remote user I cant see the local network **`192.168.20.xxx`**.

any pointers for me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is clearly explained here:

https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/

You have to set the static routes on both routers and set the ip forward on the raspberry pi